# JSF's SelectItems' itemLabel works even with incorrect var ref

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I came across this piece of code on Primefaces' official doc site for [p:selectOneRadio](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml).

Managed Bean **RadioView.java**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RadioView {
    ... 
    private String city2;
    private List<String> cities;
    ...
}
```

UI File **oneRadio.xhtml**

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="city2" value="#{radioView.city2}" layout="responsive" columns="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{radioView.cities}" var="c" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}"/> 
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

How does the `itemLabel="#{city}"` and `itemValue="#{city}"` declaration works here even if the `var` defined is `c` and not `city`?

Comment: Sure I will report the typo. But the code actually works, with the typo!

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7856

Comment: Probably resolves `#{city}` to null, and assumes that itemLabel and itemValue is the list value (String) itself by default.